# Ember integration test for action with computed variable

Tags: integration-testing

Using Ember cli 2.9 I'm making a simple app to convert swiss francs to euros. The app works fine manually in my browser but the integration test I've written for the converter fails. It exists as an Ember component called home-index

Template:

```
<h2>INPUT GOES HERE</h2>

{{input value=userInput class="user-input" placeholder="enter your francs please"}}

<button class="convert-button" {{action 'convertInput'}}>CONVERT</button>

<div class="display-output">{{outputNumber}}</div>
```

Component logic:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

 userInput: "",
 outputNumber : 0,

 numberifiedInput: Ember.computed('userInput', function() { 
  let userInput = this.get('userInput');
  return parseFloat(userInput);
 }),

 actions: {
  convertInput() {
   var input = this.get('numberifiedInput');
   var converted = input * 0.93;
   this.set('outputNumber', converted);
  }
 }
});
```

Integration test:

```js
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('home-index', 'Integration | Component | home index', {
  integration: true
});

test('should recieve input from user and display output', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);

  this.render(hbs`{{home-index}}`);
  this.$(".user-input").val("1");
  this.$('.convert-button').click();

  assert.equal(this.$(".display-output").text(), "0.93", "should display correct converted amount");    

});
```

When using the app manually in the browser the value is correctly converted from 1 to 0.93 and displayed in the div. However, the integration test returns "NaN' instead of "0.93".

When I write the test into an acceptance test instead, it passes and gives the correct result. This led me to believe it was due to the use of asynchronous helpers.

I then tried to rewrite the integration test wrapped in an imported wait method as follows:

```js
return wait()
  .then(() => {
    assert.equal(this.$(".display-output").text(), "0.93", "should display correct converted amount");    
  });
});
```

But still gives "NaN" as a result in the integration test.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

PS. Sorry about posting in snippets, stack overflow code blocks are being temperamental..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try triggering the events 'input' and 'change' on the input field after setting the val.

```
$('.user-input').val('1');
$('.user-input').trigger('input');
$('.user-input').change();
```

See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.9.1/packages/ember-testing/lib/helpers/fill_in.js#L15 for how the acceptance test helper `fillIn` does it (but without jQuery).

If an acceptance test is acceptable, it can be a better way to test this sort of thing since the built-in helpers handle the various events that would normally be triggered by user interaction.